# JSX TS error on function that is only called when value is defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx

Why is this a TS error `Object is possibly 'undefined` when i'm only calling updateText when text is defined?

```
type ButtonProps = { text: string | undefined };

function Button({ text }: ButtonProps) {
  const updateText = () => {
    text.split("1");
  };

  return text && updateText();
}
```

Comment: updateText is defined before the place where typescript can assert that text is indeed not undefined. So at the point of the function definition, typescript can’t infer that it’s not undefined. Consider this: extract the function outside of the component body and pass text as an argument

Comment: The validity of `updateText` shouldn't depend on where it is called from. You could call it another time, should that then suddenly invalidate the place where it is defined?

Comment: If that ever happened then I would expect TS to error. I hoped TS might be able to infer that text can never be undefined in this example. If the && was an if TS would know so why is the `&&` so different I wonder.

Comment: "If the && was an if TS would know" - no, it wouldn't. Also, I still don't believe TS should do what you ask for. You should put the check into `updateText`, or close over an additional local variable, which does not allow for `undefined`. Just to make this clear: you are asking for something similar to writing a function `(p: string | undefined) => p.split('')` to not give an error, simply because it wasn't called with `undefined` yet. You checked at the only call-site, but again, what stops you from not checking the next time?